# CTE Pivot in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have been given a task to complete and frustrated with the syntax on this one,

Our db in SQL Server has a ragged hierarchy with 6 columns, i have created some insert code to get it perfect.

Desired output is to find the top layer for each CostCentreID that is under 100 - 
and to skip out any layers where the isservice and issector are both SET to 0, you can see in my desired output ignoreme and corp services rows should not come out - and i need it pivoted horizontally so the CostCentres are along the top.

```
CREATE table #test
(
    ParentID       int, 
    CostCentre     varchar(max), 
    CostCentreID   int, 
    CostCentreCode varchar(max), 
    ISService      bit, 
    ISSector       bit
)
GO
INSERT into #test VALUES(10289,'Legal',88,'0107',0,0)
INSERT into #test VALUES(10291,'ML Corp',10289,'MLCorpServ',0,1)
INSERT into #test VALUES(10292,'IgnoreMe',10291,'MLCorpServ',0,0)
INSERT into #test VALUES(10000,'Corp Services',10292,'CorpSvcs',1,0)
INSERT into #test VALUES(10000,'Corp Services Top',10000,'CorpSvcstop',0,0)
```

Desired output:

```
Parent1,           Parent2,                      Parent 3,            Parent4
Legal         ML Corporate Services         Corporate Services         xxxxxetc
```

Annoyingly each heirarchy has a different number of potential parents - I think the maximum is 9 parents.

Can someone help me to pivot the data and figure this out?

Regards

J

Hi there

I am 99% there Jayvee thankyou for your help.

My output is as follows:

88,10289
88,10289,10291
88,10289,10291,10292
88,10289,10291,10292,10000

The desired line is:

88,10289,10292 - because 10291, and 10000 both have 0,0 for isservice and issector

How do i still count them as part of the heirarchy ladder when calculating it, but not output them? Basically i want the highest Sector OR Service to be the last item in each row

Comment: my desired output got all messed up wqith the spacing 
Desired output is the costcentres pivoted horizontally - sorry for any confusion

Comment: Rejected "comment" edit: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/5513493

Comment: @JacodeGroot Please stop making trivial edits to correct spelling on old posts. You are flooding the main page by bumping old posts with activity that isn't necessary. Not only that but you aren't fully improving the posts with these edits, they are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Stopped. Didn't realise I was pushing up old posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can `left join` nine times:

```
select  child
,       parent1.name
,       parent2.name
,       parent3.name
...
from    YourTable child
left join
        YourTable parent1
on      parent1.ID = child.ParentID
left join
        YourTable parent2
on      parent2.ID = parent1.ParentID
left join
        YourTable parent3
on      parent3.ID = parent2.ParentID
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is a string builder with CTE, something like this:

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT CAST(CostCentreid AS VARCHAR(max))  + ',' + CAST(parentid AS VARCHAR(max)) sb 
    FROM #test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sb +',' + CAST(parentid AS VARCHAR(max)) 
    FROM r 
    JOIN #test t ON rtrim(CAST(t.costcentreid AS VARCHAR(max)))=rtrim(right(r.sb,CHARINDEX(',',reverse(r.sb))-1))
    WHERE t.parentid<>t.costcentreid
)
SELECT * FROM r
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Hi Jayvee - thanks for the answer .. i tried executing it and it returned the costcentrecodes which is great - but how do i only get the bottom one .. the result set came back like this:

Comment: depending on the meaning of your data you may have better options but a simple one could be replacing the "select * from r" with this:     SELECT * FROM r WHERE LEN(sb)=(SELECT MAX(LEN(sb)) FROM r)

Comment: hi jayvee 
99% there - I edited my first post :) thankyou for your help its awesome !